# Outlook 2003 - Change Email Account Settings Externally via VB.Net / API / Etc

Tags: smtp, profile, outlook-2003

I have an end user that, when downloading email at home (on his laptop), can't use his "work" email server (SPF settings). He must change to the local cable company outgoing server. To do this, he has to start Outlook, go to Account settings, and change the SMTP server from mail.companydomain.com to rr.tx.twc.com. And of course, at work, the RR domain doesn't work there, so he has to change it back to the company SMTP server.

It would be great if shortcuts could be placed on his laptop of:
1) Set home SMTP
2) Set work SMTP

Make sense?

I've searched the SMTP server settings in the registry and they are not there (that I can find), so I'm assuming they are encrypted or stored in the PST file?

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: see [here](http://www.verdewek.com/Free/OutlookConfig/Default.aspx).

Comment: Wow, I love this site! That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!